# Attempt to use Restricted Class: org.apache.catalina.tribes.util.Arrays

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud

I am trying to deploy a java app on WSO2 cloud.
When running i get this Exception:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org/apache/catalina/tribes/util/Arrays
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:329)
org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)


root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Security Violation, attempt to use Restricted Class: org.apache.catalina.tribes.util.Arrays
```

However, this app is working fine locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `java.util.Arrays` instead of `org.apache.catalina.tribes.util.Arrays` and it worked now